# ng-repeat view display not corresponding to JSON data

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json, angularjs

I have JSON information I want to display in Angular, however, when I do nested ng-repeat, the data is not displaying.

JSON File(index.json.jbuilder)

```
    json.array! @devices do |device|  
     json.array! device.employees do |employee|
      json.id device.id
      json.bfid device.bfid
      json.serial_number device.serial_number
      json.device_type device.device_type
      json.make device.make
      json.model device.model
      json.year device.year
      json.description device.description
      json.purchase_price device.purchase_price
      json.damage device.damage
      json.first_name employee.first_name
      json.last_name employee.last_name
     end
   end
```

Angular File(index.html.erb)

```
<tr ng-repeat="device in devices | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse | filter:search">
  <tr ng-repeat="employee in devices.employees">
     <td>{{ device.bfid }}</td>  
     <td>{{ device.serial_number }}</td>
     <td>{{ device.device_type }}</td>
     <td>{{ device.make }}</td>
     <td>{{ device.model }}</td>
     <td>{{ device.year }}</td>
     <td>{{ device.description }}</td>
     <td>{{ device.purchase_price }}</td>
     <td>{{ device.damage }}</td>
     <td>{{ employee.first_name }}</td>
     <td>{{ employee.last_name }}</td>  
  <tr>
 <tr>
```

http://postimg.org/image/hnfrv6mkf/

Comment: If you remove this entire piece of code, does it work? | orderBy:sortType:sortReverse

Comment: No same thing. It doesn't display it

Comment: <tr ng-repeat="employee in devices.employees">   should be  <tr ng-repeat="employee in device.employees">

Comment: can you add a data sample? A piece of JSON we can see?

Comment: I added it as picture in the link. It's from my JSON. http://postimg.org/image/hnfrv6mkf/

Comment: I see an array of arrays with just one element in it. The json is not correct

Comment: How come I see the data that is from my JSON such as device.id. I also see data from employees table, employee.first_name. How should my JSON be?

Comment: The employee.first_name and employee.last_name is coming from device.employees association from a join table. It's not from devices table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so I made it into one array. Now in angular I just use one ng-repeat.

```
json.array! @devices do |device|
    json.first_name device.employees[0].first_name
    json.last_name device.employees[0].last_name
end
```

Answer (score 1):

in the inner ng-repeat you are using the wrong object: it should be `device.employees` (singular) and not `devices.employees`:

```
<tr ng-repeat="employee in device.employees">
```

Comment: I changed it to device.employees, still nothing displayed.

Comment: try to start with a simple `<tr ng-repeat="device in devices"><td>{{ device.bfid }}</td></tr>` and if it works gradually add things.

Comment: Without device.employees, it works fine. When I nest the ng-repeat it doesn't display anything.

Comment: are you 100% sure `device.employees` contains elements?

Comment: For example. In Rails I can do. Device.first.employees.first.first_name